# Bash command to delete folders within a specific directory

Tags: bash, directory, cron, find, locate

I'd like to create a bash script/ cron job that does the following.

Given a parent directory: `$HOME/parent`
I want to remove every folder in a path that ends with `/directory/to/remove/from`

So basically I'd like to call `rm -fr $HOME/parent/***/directory/to/remove/from/*` if the `directory/to/remove/from` is older than x days.

`***` represents any number of folders that may be between the start and end of the path we're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Check find command help. I think it should be something like

```
find $HOME/parent -type d -name "directory/to/remove/from" -mtime +5 -delete
```